# UItableviewcell Reuse issue in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

Hello guys i think almost everyone who is in ios development may come across the issue of reuse of the UITableCell by using following code line.

```
 RZRestaurantListingCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I have search lot about this but not getting any desire answer so please help me out in this case.

**I have the same issue as most of iPhone developer having after reusing the cell.
I have the UIProgressView inside my cell and one button is there for downloading the video and i am showing the progress there in progress view how much is left.
So Now what i have problem is when i have more data and going out of the screen at that time i am press the download button on very first row of the UITableviewCell  then i am scrolling down so the progress also shown in bottom random one cell so the UI changes in two cell rather then one.**

Comment: You don't show how you update the progress bars, which is probably your issue. You need to use cellForRowAtIndexPath to find which progress bar to update. Don't keep a reference to the cell or the progress bar anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement -prepareForReuse method in your custom cell class and set all cell properties to default value.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
```

> If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse
>   identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned
>   from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. For
>   performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that
>   are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection
>   state. The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
>   should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell
>   object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is
>   not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke
>   the superclass implementation.

Refer here for more, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse

Comment: Hey vijay i have implemented that method but now working and reset my cell also there.

Comment: Means i have already use that method but not worked ... after that i have post the question here...let me try again

Comment: Can you check with debugging that what cell have before value binding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `prepareforreuse` `method` to `clear` content of cell before using it... e.g.

```
-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    self.textLabel.text = @"";
    self.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
    self.imageView.image = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a progress value inside the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RZRestaurantListingCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // If the cell is reused, the `-prepareForReuse:` of `UITableViewCell` will be called.

    //!! Assign current progress value to this cell, otherwise, the progressBar.value may look like a random value. 
    //!! Because the current cell is reused from a disappeared cell.
    cell.progressBar.value = ... ;

    return cell;
}
```

The design may be complex, because the progress may be updated continuously when the cell is on the screen.

Comment: I think you are right i need to set the progress value in the cellForRow