# Can I avoid reusing some UICollectionViewCells?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Normally we reuse UICollectionViewCells. We do

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SomeCell* cell =  [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellId forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell configureWithData:someData];
    return cell;
}
```

But sometimes configuring one specific cell is time consuming(for example when it should remove all former subviews and create new ones), and it only needs to be configured once. I only want to call the method `configureWithData` once, not every time when user scrolls that cell in and out of the screen.

When using UITableView I would store that specific cell as a property. But I found that I can't do the same thing with UICollectionView. When I do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.collectionView registerClass:SomeCell.class forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellId];
    self.specificCell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellId forIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]];
    [self.specificCell configureWithData:someData];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return self.specificCell;
}
```

That cell's position is far from correct, it went flying to other sections.

So I'm wondering how else could I avoid reusing UICollectionViewCell, and always use one specific cell for one specific section? If I can't do that, then is there any way I could avoid calling `configureWithData` every time the user scrolls that cell in and out of the screen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495727/uitableviewcell-reuse-issue-in-ios

Comment: @PKT Thank you, but that post didn't seem to solve my problem. I know how to reconfigure one reused cell, I just want to avoid the reusing if possible.

Comment: if you want to detect scroll then you can use scrollview delegate method . it calls when scroll is done may help

Comment: I'm sorry but you didn't seem to understand my question... Thanks anyway:)